# How to return different value types in a java method?

Tags: java, return-type

I want to create a method in which there is an if statement.  If the condition is true, then it returns say a string, otherwise it returns a boolean.

Like this (which doesn't compile):

```
public String getName() {
    String name = "Name";
    if (/* some condition */) {
        return this.name;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Simple answer - no. Complex answer - you can return an Object and have the calling method figure out which Object is that. But that is just wrong.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the above code?

Comment: No. While there are ways to achieve something *like* this (say, by returning `Object`), this is not directly possible, and in any case, would be a bad design.

Comment: No, this is not how Java works. Java is a strongly and statically typed language. A method should return values of only one type.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do that, you define a function return type and stick to it. In this sense, Java is said to be *statically typed*.

You could build yourself a class that's capable of representing a string and a Boolean value, but in your case though you could simply `return null;` for the `false` case which is idiomatic in Java:

```
public String getName(){
    String name = "Name";
    if (/* some condition */){
      return this.name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

An empty string, `return "";` is another possibility and might be easier to work with on the call sites at the expense of it being a little crude, but it will avoid the dreaded `NullPointerException` pitfalls from which `return null;` could suffer.

Answer (score 2):

No, but the next best thing is to return an `Optional<String>`:

```
public Optional<String> getName() {
    String name = "Name";
    if (/* some condition */){
        return Optional.of(this.name);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The caller can then use:

```
Optional<String> result = thing.getName();
if (result.isEmpty())
    // the value was "false"
```

`Optional`, which is just a thin wrapper around a value or the absence of a value, was introduced in Java 8 mainly to more elegantly handle nulls.

Comment: The advantage of returning an `Optional<String>` rather than `String` or `null` is that you avoid the case where the programmer forgets that the result of getName() could sometimes be null, and gets an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

you are breaking the coherence in the methods return value,

event thoe you can return an OBJECT, that is smelly code that will cause some neckpain in the future...

if the condition is met return a string, if not return a string with null

```
public String getName(){
    String name = "Name";
    if (conditionTrue){
      return this.name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Welcome to the world of Java! :)

The anwser to your question: Yes you can, but you shouldn't. A solution the way you wanted your code to be is:

```
public Object getName(){
    String name = "Name";
    if (/*true*/){
        return this.name;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

But you should just return null instead of the string in order to avoid using empty strings as a return for false.

```
public String getName(){
    String name = "Name";
    if (/*true*/){
        return this.name;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```